# NDSolve Error when solve n-body problem

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to build an n-body problem solver, coming over this problem

```
NDSolve::ndode: The equations {{4.0516,3.0366}[2]=={-1.66495,-3.0217}[2],{-7.91547,6.9435}[2]=={5.61725,-3.39289}[2],{-6.85727,6.18931}[2]=={7.74616,-9.17974}[2],<<6>>,{4.0516,3.0366}[1]=={-1.66495,-3.0217}[1],<<8>>} are not differential equations or initial conditions in the dependent variables {TemporaryVariable$4957,TemporaryVariable$4958,TemporaryVariable$4959,TemporaryVariable$4960,TemporaryVariable$4961,TemporaryVariable$4962}.
```

It's something about the initial value assignment, but I don't know how to fix it.
Here's my whole program:
[image]

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! To make the most of MMA.SE start by taking the **[tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)**. It will help us to help you if you, please, **[edit your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/267255/edit)** to include the code you are using in formatted form that we can copy-paste and run, instead of a screenshot. To properly format code, paste your code into the question as plain text, select it, then use the `{ }` formatting icon.  I hope you will become a regular contributor.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you are writing `x[i]` instead of `x[[i]]`.  However, this may not fix all the problems with your code, so it is important that you include the code itself in your question, instead of a screenshot.  Also, you may be interested in the example three-body problem in two dimensions for the [NBodySimulation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NBodySimulation.html) function.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!